# how to get last row value in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with following data (sample);

```
UserId  -   DeviceId    -   StartDate   -   EndDate
------------------------------------------------------
1001        D119822         11/27/2011      12/02/2011
1001        D198726         11/27/2011      12/02/2011
1001        D552833         11/27/2011      12/02/2011
1001        D980993         11/27/2011      12/02/2011
```

I have searched for some kind of `row_num` or `ordinal_position` thing, but found nothing.
How could I get the latest record from the above table without adding a serial/auto increment number column?

Comment: What is the latest record and why? What is the primary key?

Comment: @gbn: By latest record, I mean the record which was last added. And there is no primary key column in my table.

Comment: You need something to use in an ORDER BY clause. A table (set) has **no implied order** in SQL

Comment: @gbn: Thats what I want to confirm. `Is there something in-built in MySQL which can be used as the time stamp of a record`?

Comment: Your database design should reflect what you need to do with it! So alter your database adding (as example) an auto-id column.

Comment: @Marco: Cannot I do it without altering the table structure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. As @gbn told you: _"A table (set) has no implied order in SQL"_

Comment: is it  possible to get specific row direct  means i give 4 number then get 4 number row value

Comment: @Sanjay Patel: there is nothing that say "row 4" here. What you see is **not** how the RDBMS interprets it. It needs something to plug into an ORDER BY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query, i have tested it and it works for me.

```
select s.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank
from your_table s, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
order by rank DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: the rank is arbitrary over large datasets. You don't know how it will be evaluated

Comment: @gbn I don't really know if MySQL sorts data when you don't specify an ORDER BY clause. I've tested the request on several tables and it returned the correct answer so i posted it ;)

Comment: There is no order without an ORDER BY

Comment: @gbn Then the request returns rows in a random order? I thought that when you execute a `SELECT * FROM TABLE` mysql returned rows order by date of creation

Comment: I've never seen this `@rownum` thing. Would its results always be correct.

Comment: @Mudassir `@rownum` is a variable initialized in `(SELECT @rownum:=0)`. Like i've said to gbn, i've tested it on several tables and it works. I don't really know if it always be correct but i haven't found an exemple where it was incorrect.

Comment: @Fred: I got it after trying. Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

"last" can be alphabetical, time, value etc. You need to define that in a simply query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable
ORDER BY (some criteria that defines "last") DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: but my table doesn't have a `some criteria that defines` kinda thing.

Comment: @gbn No need to have criteria for this request, i think it could be solved by building a counter. Can you give me your feedback about my request?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the answer to this question is simply **NO**. MySQL does not provide you with a built in feature that let you keep track of the order in which data has been inserted.

You could add a column that auto increments (unique id) when a row is inserted, or you could add a time stamp column to keep track of the time at which the row was inserted.

If you're not allowed to manipulate the table then maybe you could add a new table to store the latest added row of data (but this is just a bad solution really).

Comment: Take a look at my request ;) You are not oblige to modify the table structure.

Comment: It always comes down to time and money. If getting the last added data is worth the time and money of restructuring the table, then that's what they should do. Maintenance and further development would also be easier and less costly if there was an auto incremented id somewhere.